# chsh: "You may not change the shell for 'username'."

Tags: chsh

I'm trying to change the default shell for my user. But I keep getting this error:

```
$ chsh
You may not change the shell for 'flimm'.
$ chsh -s "$(which bash)"
You may not change the shell for 'flimm'.
```

I'm trying to understand why I may not change the shell for my user.

Comment: Did the setuid bit get removed? Check with `ls -l /usr/bin/chsh`

Comment: Nope: `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44808 Jun 17  2021 /usr/bin/chsh`

Answer (score 7):

Since you confirmed that `/usr/bin/chsh` is setuid root (and therefore should allow non-privileged users to change their own login shell), the most likely explanation for this behavior is that either

- your current login shell was not in the /etc/shells file

or

- your current login shell was restricted (most likely `/bin/rbash`)

Ex.

```
$ grep fish /etc/shells || echo "invalid shell"
invalid shell
$ 
$ sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish testuser
$ 
$ su - testuser
Password:
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
testuser@t400s ~> chsh -s /bin/bash
You may not change the shell for 'testuser'.
testuser@t400s ~> exit
```

Note that there is no restriction on root setting a user's login shell to an invalid shell (as here), and doing so does not make an invalid shell valid by adding it to the /etc/shells file.

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/rbash testuser
$     
$ su - testuser
Password:
testuser@t400s:~$
testuser@t400s:~$ chsh
You may not change the shell for 'testuser'.
testuser@t400s:~$ exit
```

If the *target* shell was absent from the /etc/shells file, you would have received a different message:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash testuser
$ 
$ su - testuser
Password:
testuser@t400s:~$ chsh -s /usr/bin/fish
Password:
chsh: /usr/bin/fish is an invalid shell
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try with command sudo usermod -s /bin/bash flimm

Comment: I ended up using the workaround, and now I no longer experience the original issue, so I can't find the answer as to why `chsh` was displaying this error.

Answer (score 0):

The user's login shell is kept in `/etc/passwd`, and is protected from modification by regular users. You can see it with `getent passwd $USER`.
If your new shell is listed in `/etc/shells`, you can change it with:

```
sudo chsh -s $(type -p bash) $USER
```

As with all manipulations of login info, be sure to have a login session on another terminal (<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F3</kbd>) in case you break something and can't login.

Comment: ... but `/usr/bin/chsh` should be setuid to permit the user to change their own shell **without** sudo